# Python unittest successfully asserts None is False

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Why does `assertFalse` succeed on `None`?

```
import unittest

class TestNoneIsFalse(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_none_is_false(self):
        self.assertFalse(None)
```

Results:

```
> python -m unittest temp
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

It seems as if this behaviour invites errors where a function does not always return a value. For example:

```
def is_lower_than_5(x):
    if x < 5:
        return True
    elif x > 5:
        return False

....

def test_5_is_not_lower_than_5(self):
   self.assertFalse(is_lower_than_5(5))
```

The above test would pass even though it should fail. It is missing an error in the code that should be caught.

How should we assert that the value is literally `False` and not merely false in a boolean context? e.g.

```
self.assertEquals(False, None)  # assert fails. good!
```

Comment: I'd say your test uncovered a bug in your function. It *should* return `False` if `x` is 5, since 5 is not lower than 5.

Comment: @chepner Unfortunately, it looks like I have to use `assertIs(... False)` to uncover the bug. The test passes using `assertFalse`.

Comment: A better idea is to not use True and False if you need a 3-way distinction between possible return values. Consider using 0, positive, and negative integers (like `cmp`), then use `assertEqual`, `assertLess`, and `assertGreater`.

Comment: Doesn't this actually show that your function already works just fine? If you have `if it_lower_than_five(number):` somewhere else in your code, as `None` is false-y, the correct behaviour will occur. If you *really need* the return value to actually *be* `True` or `False`, then you *should* be more specific in your test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the advice! You're right I don't _need_ the return value to be True or False, per se, but I personally think using `assertIs` is preferable in this instance to prevent possible maintenance issues in the future arising from the missing `x == 5` case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`None` is falsy, as well as `0`, `""`, `[]`, ...

`assertFalse` does not check whether the given value is `False` by identity. This behavior is consistent with the `if` statement:

```
if not None:
    print('falsy value!')
```

Similarly, `assertTrue` does not check whether a value is `True`, and as such values like `1`, `"abc"`, `[1, 2, 3]` pass the test. See [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more information.

This behavior is also [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue):

> ```
> assertTrue(expr, msg=None)
> assertFalse(expr, msg=None)
> ```
>
> Test that *expr* is true (or false).
>
> Note that this is equivalent to `bool(expr) is True` and not to `expr is True`

If you really want to be sure that a value is `True` or `False`, use [`assertIs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs).

Comment: I don't like it, but I suppose I must accept it. For future vim users: `%s/assert\(True\|False\)(\(.*\))/assertIs(\2, \1)/`

Answer (score 2):

Your case is actually pointed out in the documentation:

> Note that this is equivalent to bool(expr) is True and not to expr is
>   True (use assertIs(expr, True) for the latter).

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertFalse

Answer (score 0):

Python default return value for functions is `None`.

Python also implements [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python), so some values are threated as *falsey*, those are

- empty string
- integer zero
- boolean False
- empty list
- empty tuple

So yes, you should implement it as `self.assertEquals(False, None)` if you want to explicitly check the `False` boolean value. This is not a good idea, in python you can just do

```
if my_value:
    print 'truthy value'
else:
    print 'falsey value'
```

You could design your test cases using [boundary-value analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis) to check your corner cases.