# Pytest version of Unittest assertIs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

this is the pytest version of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038519/python-unittest-successfully-asserts-none-is-false).

I wrote the following test

```
def test_find_winner():
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'A', 'T'))==2
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'T', 'L'))==1
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'L', 'T'))==2
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'A', 'B'))==0
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'E', 'T'))==0
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'E', 'A'))==0
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'B', 'D'))==0
```

For all the assert statements which equals to 0. I failed to catch that I was returning the wrong type. I was returning `False`(A Bool) instead of `0`(an int).

Unittest has an [assertIs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs) function, but it seems that pytest only uses assert for its tests. Are there any equivalent functions or pytest alternatives to get around truthey and falsey evaluation

```
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'B', 'D'))==0
```

edit: Hi all thanks for the response, I understand why 0 and False should be equal but its just that I was initially evaluating it to False but would have missed it out completely if I did not spot it as my test was still passing.

Tried what @jonrsharpe suggested and its just what I needed.

```
assert(find_winner(easy_games, 'B', 'D')) is 0
```

Comment: `assert find_winner(easy_games, 'B', 'D') is 0` is the equivalent, but if you need that, you must be doing something wrong... "If it quacks like a duck, then it is a duck" is Pyhon phylosophy, and `False` certainly quacks same as `0` ;)

Comment: If `assertEqual(x, y)` -> `assert x == y`, then `assertIs(x, y)` -> `assert x is y`. But it doesn't really matter that you're returning False not 0; as the output of the test tells you, they're equal.

Comment: `assertIs` is the wrong test anyway. The property you need to test isn't that the return value is the same object as anything else. The property you need to test is that its type is `int` (and not a subclass) and its value is 0.

Comment: (While `False` *is* equal to `0`, returning `False` is still almost certainly a bug that should be tested for. The contract of this `find_winner` is much more likely to be "return 0 in this case" than "return something that compares equal to 0 with `==`", and clients may rely on properties like `str(0) == '0'` that `False` doesn't have.)